# creating a table with nested data in Angular and mongoose

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm attempting to show the contents of a nested array field in a mat-table, with little luck.

I have the following code ( in a file called employee.component.ts):

```
  employee: Employee;
  usages: Usage[]; 
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Usage>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["Asset","endDate","startDate"];
  private employeeId: string;

  constructor(
    public employeesService: EmployeesService,
    public route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
        this.employeeId = paramMap.get("employeeId");
        this.employeesService.getEmployee(this.employeeId)
        .subscribe(employeeData => {
          this.employee = {
            id: employeeData._id, 
            fullName: employeeData.fullName, 
            department: employeeData.department,
            location: employeeData.location,
            usages:  employeeData.usages,
            startDate: employeeData.startDate,
            endDate: employeeData.endDate,
          };
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Usage>(this.usages);
        });       
    });   
  } 
}
```

Utilizing the following model:

```
export interface Employee {
  id: string;
  fullName: string, 
  department: string, 
  location: string,
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  usages: String,
}
```

which creates the following data output:

```
  Employee [  {
        "_id": "5ebf58b861930c1268a13e6a",
        "fullName": "Joe Fisher",
        "department": "Accounting",
        "location": "LA",
        "startDate": "2020-05-01T07:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": null,
        "createdBy": "5eaf2923436e41171dd29bc7",
        "createdDate": "2020-05-16T03:06:32.948Z",
        "usages": [{
                "_id": "5ec0c816655ede67bff0711f",
                "employeeId": "5ebf58b861930c1268a13e6a",
                "assetId": "5eb4765e2f3fd40fbfa2cccd",
                "startDate": "2020-05-16T07:00:00.000Z",
                "endDate": "2020-05-31T07:00:00.000Z",
                "createdBy": "5eaf2923436e41171dd29bc7",
                "createdDate": "2020-05-17T05:13:58.378Z",
                "asset": "Surface Pro",
                "id": "5ec0c816655ede67bff0711f"
          }]
    }]
```

I am trying to make a mat-table of the "usages" array field from the Employee record. however, with the following code (in my employee.component.html file), I do not receive any data in my mat-table.

```
 <h1>{{ employee.fullName }}</h1>

<div class="example-container" class="mat-elevation-z2">

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z3">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="startDate">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> startDate </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let usage of employee.usages"> {{ usage.startDate }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="endDate">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> endDate </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let usage of employee.usages"> {{ usage.endDate }} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

hey @afish in fact i'm not sure but try to modify this ligne

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Usage>(this.usages);
```

to :

```
 this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Employee>(this.Employee);
```

and `dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Usage>;`
to

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Employee>;
```